# Javascript - multiple tasks in one function not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I got a script to trim http or https from a form inputs.

This is my script :

```
          function MakeLinkSafe(){  
                var f = document.getElementById('f') 
                str = trim(f.value);  
                if(str.substr(0, 7) == 'http://'){  
                    f.value = str.substr(7);  
                }  
                else if(str.substr(0, 8) == 'https://'){
                    f.value = str.substr(8);  
                }
                return true; 




                var fb = document.getElementById('fb')
                str = trim(fb.value);  
                if(str.substr(0, 7) == 'http://'){  
                    fb.value = str.substr(7);  
                }  
                else if(str.substr(0, 8) == 'https://'){
                    fb.value = str.substr(8);  
                }
                return true;


            }
```

When I put a url in my "f" input while I leave my "fb" empty and vice versa, it's working. But when I put url in both of the input. It doesn't work.

Is there any problem ith my codes ? Thank you

Comment: Anything after `return true;` will not execute. You're returning from the function too early.

Comment: so i have to put return true at the end of the code?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of return there but yes, the return in the middle is what is breaking it for sure.

Comment: @Latif: yes, you should do that.

Comment: Thank you. Putting the return true at the end of the code solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a return statement after the check on the "f" element...

Change your code as follows:

```
function MakeLinkSafe() {
    var checkF = function () {
        var f = document.getElementById('f');
        str = trim(f.value);  
        if (str.substr(0, 7) == 'http://') {  
            f.value = str.substr(7);  
        }  
        else if (str.substr(0, 8) == 'https://') {
            f.value = str.substr(8);  
        }
        return true; 
    }

    var checkFB = function () {
        var fb = document.getElementById('fb');
        str = trim(fb.value);  
        if (str.substr(0, 7) == 'http://') {  
            fb.value = str.substr(7);  
        }  
        else if (str.substr(0, 8) == 'https://') {
            fb.value = str.substr(8);  
        }
        return true;
    }
    return checkF() && checkFB();
}
```

You can, of course, create a function accepting an id to take advantage of proper functions, as mentioned by mrida above... Something along the lines of the following might do:

```
function MakeLinkSafe() {
    var check = function (id) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        str = trim(element.value);  
        if (str.substr(0, 7) == 'http://') {  
            element.value = str.substr(7);  
        }  
        else if (str.substr(0, 8) == 'https://') {
            element.value = str.substr(8);  
        }
        return true; 
    }
    return check('f') && check('fb');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplified answer. it's easier this way.

Comment: Pleasure! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

this code fragment of your code is unreachable

```
 var fb = document.getElementById('fb')
                str = trim(fb.value);  
                if(str.substr(0, 7) == 'http://'){  
                    fb.value = str.substr(7);  
                }  
                else if(str.substr(0, 8) == 'https://'){
                    fb.value = str.substr(8);  
                }
                return true;
```

before reaching the above code, the function will already have exited with a return value of true.

One way to do it is as follows (this code will fix both your links and alert true in case both are safe links.

```
        function MakeLinkSafe(linkid){
             var f = document.getElementById(linkid) 
            str = trim(f.value);  
            if(str.substr(0, 7) == 'http://'){  
                f.value = str.substr(7); return true; 
            }  
            if(str.substr(0, 8) == 'https://'){
                f.value = str.substr(8);  return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        var f = MakeLinkSafe('f');
        var fb = MakeLinkSafe('fb');

        if(f&&fb)alert(true);else alert(false);
```

Comment: You are repeating your same code twice and not using the advantage of functions.